# Nombre de Variable session segun variable de consulta

Tags: php, sql, php5, session

Quiero crear variables `$_SESSION` segun el nombre del dato que me traiga de una consulta

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($validacion)){
    borrado($row["ID_CENTRAL"]);
    $_SESSION['echo $row["ID_CENTRAL"];'] = $row["ID_CENTRAL"];
    conexion($row["ID_CENTRAL"],$row["IP"]);
}
```

SI alguien sabe com puedo lograr eso, gracias
Ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo logre:

```
   while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($validacion)){

        borrado($row["ID_CENTRAL"]);

        ${"text".$row['ID_CENTRAL']}= $row['ID_CENTRAL'];
        $_SESSION["$row[ID_CENTRAL]"] = ${"text".$row['ID_CENTRAL']};

        //echo $prueba. "<br>";                   
        conexion($row["ID_CENTRAL"],$row["IP"]);

    }

echo "$_SESSION["NOMBRE_DE_INFO_DEL_CAMPO"]";
```

//campo

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas el `echo`, puedes hacerlo asi:

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($validacion)){
    borrado($row["ID_CENTRAL"]);
    $_SESSION[$row["ID_CENTRAL"]] = $row["ID_CENTRAL"];
    conexion($row["ID_CENTRAL"],$row["IP"]);
}
```

Comment: Ya lo intente asi, y cuando iba a imprimirlo la varible queda nombrado `$_SESSION[$row["ID_CENTRAL"]]`asi que solo queda con el ultimo dato que while